# Change shortcut for 'switch to markup' in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

How do I switch the shortcut for 'toggle to markup'?

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is toggle to designer.

In Visual Studio 2008 I can toggle between the code-behind and the markup with <kbd>F7</kbd>. I got used to it and want to have the same shortcut in Visual Studio 2010 Beta2. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In 2008 you could go into Tools --> Options --> Keyboard and in the Press Shortcut keys field you could type a shortcut and it would tell you what its currently mapped to.

In 2008 its mapped to View.ToggleDesigner.

Once you know what its mapped to, type it into the Show Commands containing field, and it will filter your list down.

I don't have 2010 on this computer, so I cannot verify if you can do the same in that version.

Comment: Thanks man, you are a genius.

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard
I modified the mapping so that I have the following mappings bound:
View.ToggleDesigner(F7 (Global))
View.ViewCode (F7 (Settings Designer))
View.ViewMarkup (F7 (View Designer))

Comment: Works in VS 2010; Tools --> Options... --> Environment --> Keyboard

Comment: Works in 2010. View.ToggleDesigner is the command you need, doesn't seem to be mapped to anything by default in the C# development settings.

Comment: This does work for ASP.NET, but unfortunately it doesn't for WPF... F7 takes me from the xaml to the code but it doesn't take me back to the xaml. Any ideas what shortcuts do I need to change to do that?

Comment: Awesome.  Still works in VS2013 as well.  I never use the GUI mode designer so it is great to have a single key method to switch directly between markup and code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution: Tools -> Import & Export Settings -> Reset settings to default -> Web Developer Settings.

That indicates that it's possible to change the shortcut. Still, does anybody know where to change it in the settings directly?