# How do I create a command in Visual Studio 2010 to toggle between an aspx code behind and the file's markup, or source view?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 if I open a aspx pages code behind file then press F7 which is bound to the View.ToggleDesigner command by default I am taken to the aspx files WYSIWYG design view. To get to the actual markup, or source view, I then need to press Shift-F7.

I would like a command in visual studio that would toggle back and forth between the code behind and the aspx file's markup, or source view, ignoring the design view. A reasonable name for the command would be View.ToggleMarkup. Often times I add tags to the markup by hand, give them an ID and runat=Server attribute then switch to the code behind to add behavior or control the appearance of these new elements so this visual studio command would come in handy I believe.

So how would I create this hypothetical command View.ToggleMarkup?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984771/change-shortcut-for-switch-to-markup-in-visual-studio-2010 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554667/vs-addin-view-markup-does-exists-something-like-that

Comment: It is possible to do what you want. You simply need to find the correct values of the corresponding toggle command. Each command can be bound to a key and the current view. (e.g. code, markup, design). Just find the correct combination and post it here please

Comment: I tried @citronas's instructions from the comment section of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984771/change-shortcut-for-switch-to-markup-in-visual-studio-2010 with no success. I'm wondering if this worked for @citronas under Visual Studio 2010? After reading both previous posts I'm still at a loss for a solution besides a custom macro.

Answer (score 2):

After looking for this same thing for a little while, the only way I got it to work was by using **Macros**.

Tools -> Macros -> Macros IDE

1. Create a new Module
2. Copy this code inside the Module [How to switch between view source and markup view in Visual Studio?](http://www.karpach.com/Visual-Studio-F7-View-Source.htm) thanks to Viktar Karpach
3. Assign a shortcut key F7 to this Macro like this [How To Configure And Use Visual Studio Macros](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/how-to-configure-and-use-visual-studio-macros)

Personally, I modified the Macro source code and added the support to masterpages too
by adding this line

```
InStr(activeDoc, ".master") Or _
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I found that Shift+F8 will do the trick.